# Why $\cos^2 x-\sin^2 x = \cos 2x\;?$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I was hoping someone could explain how $\cos^2 x-\sin^2 x = \cos 2x$

After using the product rule to differentiate $\sin x \cdot \cos x$ I get the answer $\cos^2 x - \sin ^2 x$ I've come across this problem twice now and each time I've gotten the same wrong so I'm hoping someone can point out what I'm missing.

Comment: Are you sure it's $\cos^2x$ instead of $\cos2x$?

Comment: Probably a typesetting error, or a parsing error, $\cos^2 x - \sin^2 x = \cos (2x)$.

Comment: Yes sorry you are right, it should = cos(2x)

Comment: Do you know that $2\sin x\cos x=\sin (2x)$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\cos(2x) \equiv \underbrace{\cos(\color{green}{x}+\color{red}x) \equiv \cos(\color{green}x)\cos(\color{red}x)-\sin(\color{green}x)\sin(\color{red}x)}_{\text{addition identity for} \ \  \cos(\color{green}\alpha+\color{red}\beta)} \equiv \cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x).$$

Comment: So it just needed simplified by a trigonometric identify? It all seems so simple once you know how, thank you for clearing this up

Comment: @Paul: Very often, it seems that the hardest part of Calculus is the Pre-Calculus. :)

Comment: Why use $\equiv$ instead of $=$ ?

Comment: @Nick The $\equiv$ symbol, in this context, means "is equal for *all* values of $x$" (as opposed to $=$ which is usually true for only some specific values of $x$).

e.g. $x(x+1) \equiv x^2+1$ (these two expressions are algebraically equivalent-- they're equal for all $x$), vs. $2x=4$ which is true only for one value of $x$ (namely $x=2$).

Comment: @alexqwx: So, should I be using $\equiv$ in statements like $$6x\times 4 \equiv 3x \times 8$$

Comment: @Nick Strictly speaking, yes, but 99% of people don't care.

I was taught to use this by a traditional, old-fashioned teacher who was very pedantic about mathematical notation and punctuation (and I've just gotten used to it).

Wikipedia claims 

"Identities were sometimes indicated by the triple bar symbol $\equiv$ instead of the equals sign =, but this is no longer a common usage."

Comment: @Nick By the way, in my first comment, it should read $$x(x+1) \equiv x^2+\color{green} x \tag{correct}$$ rather than $$x(x+1) \equiv x^2+\color{red} 1 \tag{incorrect}.$$

Comment: @beep-boop In "for all values of x", what does "all values" mean? Because if it's not defined beforehand you could technically let "all values" be the set {2}, and then according to the "rule" you have you'd have to write $2x\equiv 4$ instead. Also this notation implies the set of all possible values of x is clear from the context, which is not always the case, and then you'd have to use actual words: "for all x in ..."  which makes the usage of $\equiv$ redundant.

Answer (score 3):

$\cos^2 (x)-\sin^2(x)=\cos(x)\cos(x)-\sin(x)\sin(x)= \cos(x+x)=\cos(2x)$

Answer (score 1):

**Algebraic proof.** $$\cos(2x)=\cos(x+x)=\cos x \cos x - \sin x \sin x = \cos^2 x - \sin^2 x$$

**Using [de Moivre's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre's_formula).** $$\cos(2x) + i \sin(2x) = (\cos x + i \sin x)^2 = \\ \cos^2 x + i^2 \sin^2 x + 2i \cos x \sin x = \cos^2 x - \sin^2 x + 2i \cos x \sin x .$$ 
From here we get $\cos(2x) = \cos^2 x - \sin^2 x.$

You can find more hints at [ProofWiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Double_Angle_Formulas/Cosine).

Answer (score 1):

It can be proved without using trigonometric identity $\cos2x=\cos^2x-\sin^2x$.
$$\cos^2x-\sin^2x=\frac{1+\cos2x}{2}-\frac{1-\cos2x}{2}=\frac{1+\cos2x-1+\cos2x}{2}=\frac{2\cos2x}{2}=\cos2x$$

Answer (score 0):

let $OPN$ be an isosceles triangle with $OP=ON=1$ and $O\hat PN = x$

let $H$ be the midpoint of $NP$ and let $M$ be the foot of the perpendicular from $P$ to the continuation of  $NO$

since the right-angled triangles $NHO$ and $NMP$ are similar we have:
$$
\frac{NP}{NM} = \frac{ON}{HN}
$$
now, using simple geometry and elementary trig on right-angled triangles we have
$$
\begin{align}
HN &= \cos x \\
ON &= 1\\
NP &= 2\cos x\\
NM &=1+\cos 2x
\end{align}
$$
thus
$$
\frac{2\cos x}{1 +\cos 2x} = \frac1{\cos x}
$$
or 
$$
\cos 2x = 2 \cos^2 x - 1
$$
but for all $x$,
$$
1 = \cos^2x + \sin^2 x
$$
giving:
$$
\cos 2x = 2 \cos^2 x - ( \cos^2x + \sin^2 x )
$$
and the required result immediately follows

Comment: :Would you please tell me how  $MN=1+\cos 2x$ in $$\begin{align}
HN &= \cos x \\
ON &= 1\\
NP &= 2\cos x\\
NM &=1+\cos 2x
\end{align}$$  ?

Answer (score 0):

the same diagram also gives an easy demonstration of the fact that 
$$
\sin 2x = 2 \sin x \cos x
$$
as @Sawarnak hinted, with the help of this result, you may apply your original idea to use calculus for an easy derivation, since differentiation gives
$$
2 \cos 2x = 2(\cos^2 x - \sin^2 x)
$$
it is not a bad idea to familiarize yourself with several different 'proofs' of such fundamental identities. this helps to clarify the different assumptions required, and leads to insights about the relationship between different mathematical idioms.

for example if $z$ is a complex number we have:
$$
\mathfrak{Re}(z^2) =  \mathfrak{Re}(z)^2 - \mathfrak{Im}(z)^2
$$
and this leads to a slightly different demonstration resting on the identity:
$$
\mathfrak{arg}(z^2) = 2 \mathfrak{arg}(z)
$$